# Is it possible to develop an entire web app in a browser? Including a database backend!

Tags: web-applications

This is my first question that I haven't been able to find an answer to on SO, so thanks to the community for all your awesome answers in the past!

I have been on the search the last few months for a platform that will allow me to build an entire web application in the browser. The reason being is because I travel quite a bit and I am unable to bring a computer with me to most locations. However at those locations I do have access to other computers that I can spend time on. Of course I can not go around installing ruby or python on these machines(most of them are windows machines anyways)

I am open to any learning any language that will allow me to use just a browser editor and a back-end that is provided by the web app. I know it is going to require an already existing online platform like http://www.erbix.com/ .

So I guess my question is has anyone ever done anything like this and if they did what platform did they use and why?

EDIT: For clarity, I do not wish to use a portable USB development environment, for a lot of the places I visit do not want anyone inserting external devices.

EDIT 2: (im nervous as this is my first question here.) I really want to make sure that the platform has a database back-end.

EDIT 3: Updated information from Erbix is swaying the question, in case others have the same question here is the documentation that is new if you notice in the comments below about the discussion from Erbix co-founder.

http://www.erbix.com/documentation/tutorial/

Comment: I did consider these things, and I should have mentioned that. A lot of the public places that I visit do not allow me to insert my own USB stick, or they have them the USB slots blocked. But I will use that when I visit the in-laws. Not to detract from the original question, what is the name of the portable rails environment?

Comment: Well, along those lines Chris you could SSH to a remote machine from any unix/mac and download a tiny ssh client for any windows machine! But the main issue in his question is "a database backend like erbix.com"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erbix.com seems to be what you're searching for, have you looked at the screencast at http://www.erbix.com/documentation/screencasts/ to see if it covers your needs?

Disclaimer: I'm one of the Erbix co-founders and your question sounds like our ideal use-case, so if you run into any kind of road-blocks with DB access or anything else, let me know or contact us via the site and we'll be very happy to help you.

Comment: I tried to watch the screen cast. The problem is it doesn't really explain things very well, and the speaker is very hard to understand ( at least for me to understand ). I would love to try erbix again, but I just can't seem to understand what is going on, and there really isn't any getting started documents that kinda walks me through your system. If there was just some documents that kinda outline what each part of the app is and maybe a walk through of how to create the hello world app more in depth and in words it would be very useful. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @97s: Will do that. We'd appreciate if you'd mention your email to us by sending a short message with it via http://www.erbix.com/feedback so that we can ping you when the tutorial is ready.

Comment: I have submitted the message. Thanks for your help. I am super excited as erbix is exactly what I need, I was just lost before. Looking forward to this information!

Comment: Updated my original question with EDIT 3 which references the new beginning of the tutorial. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered keeping a flash drive with you that contains any necessary development tools/apps? I'm pretty sure even Eclipse can function when extracted to a thumb-drive. Other than that, any assortment of ssh-like apps would allow you to remotely edit from something terminal-ish.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the erbix link - it looks very interesting.

I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but I once built a distance learning environment using CakePHP running on a memory stick. The stick server was [server2go](http://www.server2go-web.de/). It worked really well, the users could save their work etc. Only downside was it was Windows only. That was a couple of years ago and things must have moved on by now?

EDIT (Now I've seen your edit):

It really depends what sort of application you're talking about using. Of course you can build a web app like, say, a contact management system that will sit on a hosted server. You can secure login and work anywhere in the world. You could even build several applications.

If it's to be serious work, You should really be thinking about PHP, Python, ROR or something similar. Purely in terms of hosting availability I'd recommend PHP as virtually every hosting company in the world offers it. Not the case with the others. PHP also has the advantage of a zillion scripts already written and available free.

Personally, I use PHP and specifically CakePHP. I'd rather be using Python, but I don't have time to learn it and the jobs aren't out there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have been just using notepad/wordpad on most machines and writing php and then using my webhosts upload ability. I did do that for a while. However I would love to able to work much faster. I guess that I am not going to find a solution that fits my exact needs. It would be awesome if I could use RoR on a browser platform, my wife would be set! I am debating using an SSH connection to my server. The problem is the speed and error proneness when using the SSH connection for more than just a quick fix or a look at something.